# MySQL Add Based On Existing

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Table1:
TAGID | TOPIC
100   | 1
101   | 3
102   | 5

Table2:
TAGID | FRUIT
101   | Apple, Pear, Water
101   | Apple
101   | Orange, Pear, Grape
```

Basically, I need to search Table2; Fruit for the a specific value (I will set is manually) and if it exists I will create a new row in Table1 with the TAGID from Table2 and an specific number (I will send manually).  The two manual items I will change randomly as there are hundreds of possible values.  I am not sure where to start as I have very basic experience so any help appreciated.

Comment: Lookup the syntax for **INSERT INTO ... SELECT**

Comment: Since when water became a fruit? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the `TAGID`s in both tables same? Little bit unclear your question. But these are the simple queries for your tables. Try to use and get an idea.

```
SELECT FRUIT FROM Table2 WHERE TAGID = "";
INSERT INTO Table1 (TOPIC) VALUES ("");
```